# Logic for recommender application

Tags: database, logic

I am developing an application - which would have users answer maybe 10 questions - which would have 3-4 options for each question. At the end of the 10th question, based on the responses, it would need to suggest a certain solution. Since there are 100's of permutation and combinations - what's the logic that would be required to use and the database design,

thanks

**EDIT** some more detailed explanation

if my application is used to recommend a data plan from various mobile operators - based on the user answering questions like the time spent on the internet, the type of files being downloaded and so on. So, if the response to question 1 was a and question 2 was c, etc - then it would be a certain plan. If the response to question 1 was b and for question 2 it was c, then it would recommend a certain plan. So, if there were 10 questions - then the combinations can be quite large. So is there a certain algorithm that can handle this?

Comment: "what would be the logic?" how could we possibly tell it without you providing us with necessary information. "what would be the database design?" This is quite simple: USERS table, QUESTIONS table and ANSWERS table which would refer to the two others.

Comment: I thought the question was clear enough - anyway - for e.g. if my application is used to recommend a data plan from various mobile operators - based on the user answering questions like the time spent on the internet, the type of files being downloaded and so on. So, if the response to question 1 was a and question 2 was c, etc - then it would be a certain plan. If the response to question 1 was b and for question 2 it was c, then it would recommend a certain plan. So, if there were 10 questions - then the combinations can be quite large. So is there a certain algorithm that can handle this?

Comment: To be more precise, there are between 3^10 (59,049) and 4^10 (1,048,576) permutations. The common simplistic method is for each answer to add or substract points from possible candidates, depending on how well the answer suits them. The candidate with most points at the end "wins".

Answer (score 0):

**I. what would be the logic?**

If I understand correctly, you would define "rules" such as

```
If the answer to question 5. is either A or B then the suggested plan would be planB, otherwise execute the rest of the rules.
```

So you would use a [rule engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_rules_engine) e.g.: http://www.jboss.org/drools/

**II. what would be the database design?**

This is quite simple:

- USERS table,
- QUESTIONS table and
- ANSWERS table which would refer to the two others

Possibly there would be a QUESTIONNAIRE table as well, and the QUESTIONS table would refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a 'quick' comment, consider letting the user see changes in what company they could be recommended as they answer every question.

For example, if I am most interested in price that would be the question I would answer first and immediately see the 3 cheapest plans/products recommended to me.

The second question could be coverage and if I then could see the 3 plans with best coverage (in my area) that would be interesting too.

When I answer the third question about smart phone features and I say I want internet, then the first question should spit out the 3 cheapest plans/products that include internet, obviously they could change.

And so on...

Maybe it also could be a good idea to let the user "dive into" each question and see the full range of options for that answer. As a user I would appreciate that.

Above comments is just how I would appreciate if a form was made for me, I don't want to answer 10 questions about stuff I'm not really putting any value on, each user is different and will prefer to make their choice on their questions.

So, based on above it would be like a check list where the top answers would be the plans/products with the most fitting check marks. And to give immediate responses (as the user answer/alter each question), here AJAX would probably be your choice.